# python program to takes a string and returns a list without using any builin like eva() but can we use string built in function

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

i need the below solution but i am not able to get the solutions -takes a string returns a list

```
i/p:  "[(694, 104), (153, 236), (201, 106), (601, 427)]"
o/p: 
(694, 104)
(153, 236)
(201, 106)
(601, 427)
```

i have written the below code-

```
def convertor(string):
    result = (string.split("  "))[0]
    return result


string1 = "[(694, 104), (153, 236), (201, 106), (601, 427)]"

out=convertor(string1.replace("[","").replace("]",""))
print(out)
```

current output i am getting --(694, 104), (153, 236), (201, 106), (601, 427)
but i need the output in above mentioned format

Comment: What is the source of such a string? Why can you only use string methods? In that case, you basically have to write some sort of parser.

Comment: Please do not re-post the same question

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.replace("), (", ")\n(")` as follow:

```
def convertor(string):
    result = (string.split("\n"))
    return result

string1 = "[(694, 104), (153, 236), (201, 106), (601, 427)]"

out=convertor(string1.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("), (", ")\n("))

for tpl in out:
    print(tuple(tpl))
```

The output will be:

```
(694, 104)
(153, 236)
(201, 106)
(601, 427)
```

Comment: Thank you... but when i am writing print(type(out)   it is showing <type 'str'>.

it should be tuple type right?

Comment: @AshishKumar note that convert the string to a tuple, in this particular case is absolutely useless. If you want you can convert all the strings in out to tuples

Comment: is there any other solution to get the above output

Comment: @AshishKumar there are probably infinite solution. What are you looking for?

Comment: the code which you have updated that output  is totally diffrent 



('(', '6', '9', '4', ',', ' ', '1', '0', '4', ')')
('(', '1', '5', '3', ',', ' ', '2', '3', '6', ')')
('(', '2', '0', '1', ',', ' ', '1', '0', '6', ')')
('(', '6', '0', '1', ',', ' ', '4', '2', '7', ')')

Comment: output format should be  like 

(694, 104)
(153, 236)
(201, 106)
(601, 427)   right?

Comment: Can you provide some different code that meets my expectation. if you have some other idea

Comment: @AshishKumar you're right, I am unable to get the string converted to tuple without all characters being separated, sorry